# How can i make multiple modes and that the program detects if its bimodal or trimodal

Tags: java, arrays

I can only do it with one number for example
3,4,5,2,3
the program detects that the mode is 3 
but the problem is when there are multiple modes and the program only detects the first one that repeats 
for example 
3,3,4,4,5,6
It will detect only 3 as mode

Here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class mode
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This program will show below the mode ");    
       int counter = 0;
       String cant,dat;
       int maximumtimesthatisrepeated = 0;
       double mode = 0;
       cant=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the amount of data to be registered:");
       counter =Integer.parseInt(cant); 
       double[] DAT = new double[counter]; 
       for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) 
       {
       dat=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter data:    ");
       DAT[i] =Double.parseDouble(dat);
       }
      for (int i = 0; i < DAT.length; i++) {
      int timesthatisrepeated = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < DAT.length; j++) {
      if (DAT[i] == DAT[j]) {
      timesthatisrepeated++;
     }
     }
     if (timesthatisrepeated > maximumtimesthatisrepeated) {
     mode = DAT[i];
     maximumtimesthatisrepeated = timesthatisrepeated;
     }
     }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The mode is " + mode +" and repeats "+maximumtimesthatisrepeated+"times");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
your code is only able to detect the first most mode because you only test for lager mode and mode can only hold one value.

**Solution:**
in your if statement at the end you have to check also for the equal case and your mode variable needs to be able to hold several values.

**Example:**

```
double mode = 0; //replace this with line below
ArrayList<Double> mode = new ArrayList<>();
```

add the import

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

modify your if statement like this:

```
if (timesthatisrepeated > maximumtimesthatisrepeated) {
//  mode = DAT[i];  deprecaded line
    mode.clear();
    mode.add(DAT[i]);
    maximumtimesthatisrepeated = timesthatisrepeated;
} else if (timesthatisrepeated == maximumtimesthatisrepeated) { // checks for additional modes
    if (!mode.contains(DAT[i])) {    // recognices duplicates
        mode.add(DAT[i]);
    }
}
```

**Note:**
I used `ArrayList` for simplicity, because it offers `.add()`, `.clear()` and `.contains()` implementations. A normal array can also be used, however then you have to manually write this actions.
The nuber of modes can be read through `mode.size()`.

(Sorry for spelling or grammer errors :))